# for loop until xml attribute is not null. start on last row - javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, loops, nodes

So, I have the ff. xml, xmlSemesters.

```
<Semesters>
    <Row SemesterID="60" SequentialOrderNumber="1" />
    <Row SemesterID="61" SequentialOrderNumber="2" />
    <Row SemesterID="54" SequentialOrderNumber="3" />
    <Row SemesterID="" SequentialOrderNumber="4" />
    <Row SemesterID="" SequentialOrderNumber="5" />
</Semesters>
```

I want to be able to select the LAST NODE with a SemesterID value(in this case, the 3rd node). The number of rows are dynamic, the last node with semesterID varies, the sequentialordernumber attribute just increments depending on the number of nodes of the xml.

So currently, my way of selecting the last node with a semesterID value is this:

```
var xmlLength = xmlSemesters.getElementsByTagName("Row").length;
var firstRow = xmlSemesters.selectSingleNode("//Row[@SemesterID!='']");
var lastRow = xmlSemesters.selectSingleNode("//Row[@SequentialOrderNumber<='"+xmlLength+"' and @SemesterID!='' and @SequentialOrderNumber>'"+firstRow.getAttribute("SequentialOrderNumber")+"']");
```

So I have a firstRow that will get the first node with a semesterID value. And then I have a lastRow that should get the last node with a semesterID value. But that is not the case on my code, it gets the second node. So I know that it is wrong.

Is there any other way so that I can get the last node with a semesterID value?

I'm thinking of looping the xml, like starting off with the node equal to the xmlLength. so In this case 5, so after it detects that the semesterID is null, it will loop again and subtract the sequentialordernumber attribute by 1 until it reaches a node with a SemesterID value.

I just don't know how to put that in code. Or is there any other way?

Language is javascript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var xmlRow = xmlSemesters.getElementsByTagName("Row"); //get all the Row element here
//since we are going to start at the end, we have to get the length 
// of xmlRow -1 because it starts with zero..if we have 3 Row element for example
// it has an index of 0,1,2 and not 1,2,3
var len = xmlRow.length - 1; // our lenght is 4 in this case
// Using for loop, we can start our loop from the end
// notice that we start our loop from len which is equals to 4
// and decrement its value using i--
for(var i = len; i > 0; i--) {
   if(xmlRow[i].getAttribute("SemesterID") != "") {
      //it's the last so...
      alert("the last node is "+xmlRow[i]);
      //...we have to break the loop.
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: good answer, please add some description to help the OP understand it, so he doesn't just Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V your code without a clue